# tkinter - updating refreshing a page/text to use new return from function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i am new to programing and have been trying to get this to work.

ranlist() is a function that returns a random color from a tuple holding colors.

randisk() is a function that returns a random shape from a tuple holding shapes.

Would like to be able to refresh the Page so it gives me a new return from these functions, currently it seems to be static, unless i create a new page, result will remain static on each page.

Would like to press a button and get new random color and shape from ranlist() and randisk() displayed on the page.

How would/could i do this?

thank you for taking the time to read this.

```
import tkinter as tk    
from tkinter import *
# python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont # python 3
import random

# containing tuple with shapes
from OneGeneralIncidentsList import GI
# containing tuple with color
from disklist import disk
#import Tkinter as tk     # python 2
#import tkFont as tkfont  # python 2

# return random shape from tuple
def ranlist():
    a=random.choice(GI)
    return a

# return random color from tuple
def randisk():
    a=random.choice(disk)
    return a



class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=14, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Press Continue for random color and shape", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Continue",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        v = tk.StringVar()
        var0 = "randon color: "
        var1 = ranlist()
        var2 = "\n"
        var3 = "random shape: "
        var4 = randisk()

        v.set(var0+var1+var2+var3+var4)

        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=v, font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)


        button = tk.Button(self, text="Next",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        v = tk.StringVar()
        var0 = "randon color: "
        var1 = ranlist()
        var2 = "\n"
        var3 = "random shape: "
        var4 = randisk()

        v.set(var0+var1+var2+var3+var4)


        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=v, font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Next",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer: quote: https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_message_widget.php

> textvariable: Associates a Tkinter variable with the message, which is
>   usually a StringVar. If the variable is changed, the message text is
>   updated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk    
from tkinter import *
# python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont # python 3
import random

# containing tuple with shapes
from OneGeneralIncidentsList import GI
# containing tuple with color
from disklist import disk
#import Tkinter as tk     # python 2
#import tkFont as tkfont  # python 2

# return random shape from tuple
def ranlist():
    a=random.choice(GI)
    return a

# return random color from tuple
def randisk():
    a=random.choice(disk)
    return a



class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=14, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Press Continue for random color and shape", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Continue",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        #button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Checking page",
            #                command=lambda: #controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
      #  button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        v = tk.StringVar()
        def message():
            var0 = "randon color: "
            var1 = ranlist()
            var2 = "\n"
            var3 = "random shape: "
            var4 = randisk()
            return (var0+var1+var2+var3+var4)

        def change_msg():
            v.set(message())


        v.set(message())


        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=v, font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)


        button = tk.Button(self, text="Next",
                           command=change_msg)
        button.pack()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```